# Нужно спарсить json из html сайта

Tags: php, html, json, api, url

Здравствуйте. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.
Есть сайт, в html странице этого сайта есть:

```
<script id='PageJson' type='text/json'>
{
"age":"32",
"name":"David",
"surname":"Johnson"
}
</script>
```

и я хочу достать с него **age, name, surname**, и вставить к себе на сайт таким путем:

человек вставляет ссылку сайта в **input**, жмет **button**, и в низу под input появляется например такое:

```
<center><b>David Johnson</b> имеет возраст <b>32</b> года</center>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, какими способами это можно осуществить?

Comment: вы можете это спарсить на сервере, а потом отдать это в виде JSON.

Comment: Я так понимаю ---грабить--- парсить этот код Вы будете не со своего сайта, а с какого-то вКонтакте? Узнайте есть ли у них API, это будет самым верным решением. А если Ваш сайт, то зачем их парсить, если эти данные уже есть у Вас на сервере???

Comment: а код не подскажете?
например с сайта coub
там есть

<script id='PageJson' type='text/json'>
{
"title":"example",
"audio":"example.mp3",
"video":"example.mp4"
}
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Качаете `HTML`-parser [`PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).
Дальше как в манах к парсеру: парсите, ищете объект, берёте содержимое, парсите через `json_decode`.

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://path.to/your/page'); // Парсим с URL, можно со строки: str_get_html
$content = $dom->find('#PageJson', 0); // Ищем по ID Ваши данные

if($content !== null) // Если найдено
  $content = json_decode($content->innertext); // Декодируем контент
```

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не мастер парсинга сайтов, но вот вам вариант:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('https://goo.gl/P7lZil');

$pattern = '=\<script id\=\'PageJson\'.*?\>(.*)\</script\>=s';

$replacement = '$1';

echo preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );
```

В итоге получится JSON, с которым, думаю, вы знаете как управляться ...

На всякий случай вот: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Чур Вас, батенька. HTML **нельзя** парсить регулярками!

Comment: @Other, я знаю: слышал; а почему нельзя — не поделитесь коротенькой понятной статейкой об этом? Что мне запомнилось, так это только то, что HTML изменчив — ну так всё вокруг меняется.

Comment: Статейки не знаю (хотя на хабре точно что-то найдётся), просто я уверен что парсить ЯП - это извращение, ибо надо учитывать возможные конструкции, нотацию, да банально какие кавычки у строки (а вдруг это не строка, а цифра?). Если очень хочется, то можно, конечно, никто не запрещает, но это верный способ запутаться и просидеть N времени на поиск: Какая из десяти скобок в регулярке отвечает за возможность захвата третьего атрибута?

Comment: Хоть и не статейка, зато коротко и понятно: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1510966 Ну и рядом там более научные объяснения, с использованием терминов вроде "грамматика Хомского"..